# Apps Not Downloading/Updating After Factory Reset

Tags: google-play-store, google-apps, google-pixel

I have a problem with my Pixel 3.  I was having an issue with Google Play not updating any of my apps over the past couple days.  After trying several things, including:

- Clearing Cache and Data
- Force Stopping Google Play
- Disabling Google Play Updates

None of those solutions worked.  I decided to do a factory reset on my phone.  However, once the phone restarted, the play store got stuck in "Completing Setup."  It was trying to install an app, but it said "Waiting for Wi-Fi." However, the phone was definitely connected to my Wi-Fi, and I have a strong and stable connection.  I decided to just cancel all the pending downloads and updates, but that didn't seem to help, as I still can't install or update any apps if I try it one by one.  I either get a "Waiting for Wi-Fi" or "Downloading..." message for the app, and nothing else happens.  I have no idea what to do next.  Does anyone know of any possible solutions?  My phone is not rooted, and I would prefer solutions that don't require that if at all possible.